# Rows are duplicating in Pivot column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

```
AccountTitle     ReportMonth     Amount     
--------------------------------------------
Visa            January          3320.00
Medical         January          1635.82     
Commission      January          2200.00    
Staff Allowance January          1215.00    
Commission      January          2200.00    
Medical         February         1636.00    
Commission      February         2200.00        
Staff Allowance March            1750.00
```

using this query

```
select AccountTitle, [January], [February], [March] 
 [dbo].MyReport 
pivot
(
sum(amount)
    for [ReportMonth] in (January, February, March)
) as P


accounttile      January  February   March
-----------------------------------------------------------
Visa             3320     null       null
Medical          1635     null       null
Commission       4400     null       null
Staff Allowance  1215     null       null   
Medical          null     1636.00    null
Commission       null     2200.00    null
Staff Allowance  null     null       1750.00
```

Now you can see medical, commission, staff allowance are duplicating.  for February is not coming properly

desired result is

```
accounttile              January    February    March
-----------------------------------------------------------
Visa                     3320       null        null
Medical                  1635       1636.00     null
Commission               4400       2200.00     null
Staff Allowance          1215       null        1750.00
```

Comment: For future questions, please format it correctly and add http://sqlfiddle.com demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have more columns that you've shown in your example

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo1`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/442459)**</kbd>

Use subquery to get only `AccountTitle, ReportMonth, amount`:

```
SELECT AccountTitle, [January], [February], [March] 
FROM (SELECT AccountTitle, ReportMonth, amount FROM MyReport) AS s
PIVOT ( 
  SUM(amount) for [ReportMonth] in (January, February, March) 
) AS pvt
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/442451)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════════════╦═════════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║   AccountType   ║ January ║ February ║ March ║
╠═════════════════╬═════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ Commission      ║ 4400    ║     2200 ║       ║
║ Medical         ║ 1635.82 ║     1636 ║       ║
║ Staff Allowance ║ 1215    ║          ║  1750 ║
║ Visa            ║ 3320    ║          ║       ║
╚═════════════════╩═════════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: Dear, Thanks a lot. I tried this before, but some how it wasn't working. In fact I had extra date column on which I was using "order by" which is causing problem. Now I removed it and its working fine. Thanks a lot once again.